# Efficiently calculate anomaly detection

Tags: python, pandas, database, machine-learning, feature-extraction

i have some problem and i hope you can help me thanks!!!!

i have a table looks like that:

| Computer | Data | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2021 | 43 |
| A | 02/01/2021 | 64 |
| A | 03/01/2021 | 333 |
| A | 04/01/2021 | 656 |
| B | 01/01/2021 | 41 |
| B | 02/01/2021 | 436 |
| B | 03/01/2021 | 745 |
| B | 04/01/2021 | 234 |

I would like to run isolation forest algorithm only on part of the table

i don't what to do it manually like df[df['Computer'] == A]['Count'] for every Computer
there are like 500 different Computers.
so i don't what to do this:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
np_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df[df['Computer'] == A]['Count'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)

# train isolation forest
model =  IsolationForest(contamination=float(.01))
model.fit(data)
df['anomaly'] = model.predict(data)
```

500 times (for A and B and C and More)
there is way to do it Efficiently
thanks!!!

As a result, it should look like this but every time its check anomaly only for A separately, B separately and so on

| Computer | Data | Count | anomaly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2021 | 43 | 1 |
| A | 02/01/2021 | 64 | 1 |
| A | 03/01/2021 | 333 | 1 |
| A | 04/01/2021 | 656 | -1 |
| B | 01/01/2021 | 41 | 1 |
| B | 02/01/2021 | 436 | 1 |
| B | 03/01/2021 | 745 | 1 |
| B | 04/01/2021 | 234 | 1 |

Comment: As I understand, you need to check anomaly from values of each computer and the values are in different range. Looping over all computers is probably the only way.

Comment: thanks, but there is a way to do it with "apply" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by `Computer` and use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to execute the function you already have over each group returning the same indexes as the original to the `anomaly` column.

```py
def train_isolation_group(group_count):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    np_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(group_count.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)

    # train isolation forest
    model =  IsolationForest(contamination=float(.01))
    model.fit(data)
    return model.predict(data)

df['anomaly'] = df.groupby('Computer')['Count'].transform(train_isolation_group)
```